# How to let Doxygen write arguments in comments with a special font or format?

Tags: doxygen

For example

```
class MyClass
{
    //* Constructs a MyClass object with a given size.
    MyClass(int size);
};
```

Doxygen will generate a document with a bold **MyClass** for the comments. How can I make it work also for the arguments as italic *size* by setting some options?

Answer (score 0):

The doxygen documentation got you covered. Depending on your output format you can use [CSS tweaks](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#minor_tweaks_header_css) or the [xml layout definition file](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout). There you can define your output in a whole new way if necessary.